# Why is flow emit crashing on release mode?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The app keeps crashing iff it's in release mode and debuggable is set to false.

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    debuggable false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
}
```

Through commenting out lines of code I have traced down the issue to the line below:

```kotlin
emit(Resource.Success(listOf(
            dayMarketChartResponse.body()!!.toMarketChartEntityList(),
            threeMonthMarketChartResponse.body()!!.toMarketChartEntityList(),
            yearMarketChartResponse.body()!!.toMarketChartEntityList(),
        )))
```

**Interesting points**

- I have fake data of which of I use to replace any one of the 3 sublists, the app does not crash.

I am probably overlooking something obvious. If you any more information to provide more context I'll update the question.

**Edit: 13 June 2023**

Data classes with `SerializedName` annotation for preservation through obfuscation

```kotlin
data class MarketChartDto(
    @SerializedName("market_caps")
    val marketCaps: List<List<Double>>,
    @SerializedName("prices")
    val prices: List<List<Double>>,
    @SerializedName("total_volumes")
    val totalVolumes: List<List<Double>>
)

fun MarketChartDto.toMarketChartEntityList() : List<MarketChartEntity> {
    return this.prices.map {
        MarketChartEntity(
            price = it[1]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: One humble suggestion is to avoid using those force unwrapping operators as it might trigger a null pointer exception, also make sure the model classes are not obfuscated.

Comment: I agree with the unwrapping operators, however I have added null checks and the issue still persists. As for the model classes, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit goes to another programmer who raised a PR in the repo and here was his explanation:

> Add proguard rules in app level to keep annotated class members.
> R8 strips annotated members of DTO - could be fixed in concrete DTO - MarketChartDto with @keep annotation, but issue could happen with other DTOs as well

```
# Keeps the SerializedName annotations on all fields in all classes.
# This is necessary for using the Gson library to serialize and deserialize objects.
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
 @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}
```